# kotlin compiler return this type of warning

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor (DYNAMIC), android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding (DYNAMIC).

Comment: In which version? 1.3.50?

Comment: yes, Kotlin version 1.3.50

Comment: You 've got your answer by Yurii!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have incremental annotation processing using `dagger` and `kapt`, please try this configuration:

- Kotlin version 1.3.60
- Dagger version 2.24
- remove any additional configs in Gradle build script related to incremental processing for dagger (for example `arguments << ["dagger.gradle.incremental": "true"]`)
- add following parameters to your `gradle.properties`:
  `kapt.incremental.apt=true`,`kapt.use.worker.api=true`,`kapt.include.compile.classpath=false`